# Can I change default highlight color when using default find functionality from browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, colors, find, highlight

E.g. on Chrome when using default functionality (ctrl+f), found results are highlighted in yellow. Can we change that color with code (for every browser)?

Example:
[image]